How can I see the output of send() when running the script from the browser?
I have a script that is sending an email. Running the script from the terminal on my local host the script is running ok.
After that, I have deployed it to the production server. I don't have access the terminal of the server, so I have to run it requesting it from the browser. The tab's spinner starts to spin when the send() function is called, and it never stops.
I would like to debug the code, so my question is how can I see the SMTPDebug's output from the browser?
The code is written using PHP 5.6 and PHPMailer 5.2:
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = 'user@company.com';
$mail->Password = '*************';
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@company.com', 'FromEmail');
$mail->addAddress('recipient@company.com', 'ToEmail');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
 
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
 
$mail->send();


Modify your PHPMailer setup to log the debug messages to a file by using the Debugoutput property. You can append the output to a log file like smtp_debug.log or echo it directly to the webpage.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) use ($logFile) {
file_put_contents($logFile, "[$level] $str\n", FILE_APPEND);
};

If your script seems to be hanging up, your hosting provider is probably blocking outbound SMTP, and your script will be waiting for the full 10-minute timeout before showing any output. Try setting SMTPDebug = 3 to get connection-level feedback.
